# How to get more than one SharePoint list using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api, api

I have created multiple lists in SharePoint 2013. I need to get the multiple list items using REST API call.

I have tried the method to get the multiple list items using API within the **for loop** but it works slowly.

Please suggest best idea to get multiple lists response.

Comment: do they have same content type ?

Comment: Instead of the loop, you can try by creating an array of your all lists name and post your request with this AJAX call, and in server side, you can retrieve data from all the lists and make a response in JSON.as mentioned here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744702/rest-api-multiple-lists-in-sharepoint

Comment: I don't have any content types . i am getting questions from SP survey list.(or suggest how to get the survey questions and responses using server side code). @GautamSheth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get data from multiple list at a same time, we need to parallel Ajax get request for getting data from more than one list.

Let's take one example:

We have two list named "**List1**" and "**List2**" and we need to get all items from both lists.

We create one module for get item:

```
var getModule = (function () {
    var baseRequest = {
        url: "",
        type: ""
    };

    var getApp = {
    };
    var getApp = {
        getRequest: getRequest,
    };

    function getRequest(endpoint, _async) {
        //var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var request = baseRequest;
        request.type = "GET";
        request.url = endpoint;
        request.headers = {
            ACCEPT: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()

        };
        return $.ajax(request);
        //return dfd.promise();
    };

    return getApp;
})();
```

After that we used jQuery **$.when** function for getting data from multiple list as shown below

```
var list1FilesInfo = $.Deferred();
var list2FilesInfo = $.Deferred();

        var dfdList1Files;
        var dfdList2Files;

        var list1URL = "Your Web URL" + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items";
        var list2URL = "Your Web URL" + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('List2')/items"



        dfdList1Files = getModule.getRequest(list1URL, true);
        dfdList2Files = getModule.getRequest(list2URL, true);

        dfdList1Files.done(function (data) {
            list1FilesInfo.resolve(data);
        });
        dfdList2Files.done(function (ldata) {
            list2FilesInfo.resolve(ldata);
        });

        $.when(list1FilesInfo, list2FilesInfo).then(function (list1Data, list2Data) {
            conssole.log('success');
        });
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: What's mean by EasyNavModule .and its not declared.

Comment: Sorry it's typo mistake. please see updated answer