# Query multiple sharepoint lists with big data

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

Our SharePoint 2016 site consists of 14 custom lists where each list has approximately 500 list items.

We wanted a way to query all 14 lists by **PR NO** which is common in all lists. We were looking for a solution implemented in JavaScript/jQuery.

I Have followed this solution to fetch all data from the 14 lists. response from server was taking too much time so we are not doing that approach.

[How to get more than one SharePoint list using REST API?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215258/how-to-get-more-than-one-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using SharePoint Search. REST API also contains Search APIs for SharePoint.

Create a result source by adding paths of all your lists in the query builder (also specify content type contains item). Check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-new-search-result-source-for-sharepoint-online/) article for creating a result source.

Your query builder should look like this.
[image]

Check if the results are as desired and then you can use the Search API referring to the Microsoft documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview).

To get results from result source using search rest api, I used the following url

```
https://spdev.sharepoint.com/sites/SPTeam/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='46cac739-2506-4f58-bef1-d4857548cf0b'
```

here instead of `querytext='*'`, you can add your **PR NO**. For Example, `querytext='PR123123'`

To build Search Rest API Queries, you can use this free tool -> [SharePoint Search Query Tool](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/releases). This tool is very useful in creating SharePoint Search REST API URLs.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, ill test it out tomorrow in work and get back to you.

Comment: Hello @harshal gite sorry for ghosting your reply for a couple of days, im having issues with the sharepoint search API


i tried multiple endpoints that related to the search api for example

`/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint`

it is giving me the following error:



`{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An unknown error occurred."}}}` do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: this is the exact issue i get

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256757/rest-query-discrete-size-error

Comment: just try tenant/_api/search/query?querytext='*' once. Let me know if you get any errors. Are you the SharePoint admin? I mean do you have access to the SharePoint admin center?

Comment: I tried that, im still getting the same error, No i do not have Access the SharePoint admin center.

Comment: ok. Search anything in the search box and check if you get results.

Comment: Im getting Access denied. Interesting, i will report that to the administrator to resolve the issue. ill get back to you after that is done.

Comment: I would like to sincerely thank you for the help you have provided. After the administrator has resolved the Access denial issue. i went to Result Source -> launched the query builder and setup up the query text to be path:https://SiteCollection once i pressed test, it queried 7500 results, which seems right. Then i used the rest api to fetch base on my given query which was: SiteCollection/_api/search/query?querytext='PRNO EXAMPLE'&sourceid='5dc9f503-801e-4ced-8a2c-5d1237132419' However i noticed a strange behavior, im getting results from different sub-sites which is not what i was expecting

Comment: + i wanted to point out, i added a new PR to the list, but it is not appearing through the rest api results..

Comment: It will not appear as soon as you add it. It takes half hour or 1 hour.

Comment: @ harshal gite well is there any overcome for that? i seen some legacy sharepoint 2010 applications this custom feature

Comment: In SharePoint Online we cannot manager the crawl rate.

Comment: got it. if theres anything you want to update in your answer so i could mark it as an accepted answer.